# Android app crashing whenever data incoming from Arduino over USB is tried to display

Tags: java, android, arduino

I'm trying to make an Android app which can receive data from Arduino connected via an OTG cable and then display it. The app opens up normally but when the user goes to the second activity and tries to display the data incoming from the Arduino which is already connected, the app crashes.

This is my `manifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />


    </activity>
    //////////////


    <activity android:name=".DoseRateActivity">

    </activity>

</application>
```

and here is the code of the DoseRateActivity java file (the second activity):

```
package com.example.ashok.radmacmac;

    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public class DoseRateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable
{


private UsbManager usbManager;
public UsbDevice deviceFound;
private UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
public UsbInterface usbInterface = null;
public UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null, endpointIn = null;

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


///////////---------------------------------------------




private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION ="com.example.ashok.radmacmac";


private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                {
                    if(device != null)
                    {
                        setDevice(device);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};




TextView tv5;
Button bt7;
Handler handler;
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
UsbDevice device;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dose_rate);
    tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION ="com.example.ashok.radmacmac";

    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);


}




public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();


    device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    //usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action))
    {
        setDevice(device);
    }
    else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action))
    {
        setDevice(null);
    }

}

private void setDevice(UsbDevice device)
{


usbInterface = null;
    endpointIn = null;
    endpointOut = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++)
    {
        UsbInterface usbif = device.getInterface(i);
        UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
        UsbEndpoint tIn = null;

        int tEndPointCnt = usbif.getEndpointCount();
        if (tEndPointCnt >= 2)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tEndPointCnt; j++)
            {
                if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                {
                    if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT)
                    {
                        tOut = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                    else if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                    {
                        tIn = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (tOut != null && tIn != null)
            {
                usbInterface = usbif;
                endpointOut = tOut;
                endpointIn = tIn;
            }
        }
    }
    if (usbInterface == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    deviceFound = device;


    if (device != null)
    {
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
        if (connection != null && connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true))
        {
            usbDeviceConnection = connection;
            Thread thread = new Thread((Runnable) this);
            thread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            usbDeviceConnection = null;
        }
    }





}

//////////////
 public void displayFromArduino(View v)
{

    usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent); //line 216, causing error

    handler = new Handler();    //allocate memory for handler
    MyThread mthread = new MyThread();
    //tv.setText("Incoming...");
    mthread.start();

}


class MyThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        do
        {
            byte x;
            String string=null;
            final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
            UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
            request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
            while (true)
            {
                request.queue(buffer, 1);
                if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        x= buffer.get(0);
                        string = Byte.toString(x);
                        handler.post(new newthread(string));
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else break;
            }


        }
        while(1==0);    //to execute only one time.

    }

}
class newthread implements Runnable
{
    String str;
    public newthread(String STR)
    {
        str=STR;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()

    {
        tv5.setText(str);
    }
}

///////////////


///////////////


public void run()
{

}


}
```

Edit: Procured the log file generated during the crash using Crashlytics. Here is the link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B63xLn9uRNbyaTFUT2RMN3JSVlk

Comment: Can you provide the error messages which are shown in the log please?

Comment: The Android device and Arduino are directly connected, there is no way I can collect the error messages.

Comment: You can use some remote logging tools (such as https://bugfender.com/ or https://try.crashlytics.com/) to view your logfiles. Without such tools you will be lost in your scenario.

Comment: So I got the log file using Crashlytics. I have given the link in the answer.

Comment: You Crashlytics log suggests there is an NPE on line 216 of your DoseRateActivity.  "NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice.getDeviceName()' on a null object reference". I would start there. Can you post that code?

Comment: @Tyler...Added the complete code of DoseRateActivity. The line 216 causing the error is:  usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent); This line is trying to show a popup asking the user for permission to connect to the device.